# Why is my string printing out twice?

Tags: c

I wanted to create a game that randomized a string and the user has to guess what the original string is, but when i display the randomized string it is printed twice. one time randomized one time not randomized. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int checkWin(char guess[], char word[]);
void jumble(char array[]);
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    char word[5] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
    char scramble[5] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
    char guess[5];
    jumble(scramble);
    printf("The jumled word is: %s\n",scramble);
    printf("Enter a guess: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
    {
        scanf(" %c",&guess[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    if(checkWin(guess,word))
        printf("You win!");
    else
        printf("You lose");
}
void jumble(char array[])
{
    int a,b,c;
    for(a = 1; a<6; a++)
    {
        b = rand()%5;
        c = rand() %5;
        if(b==c)
        {
            a--;
            continue;
        }
        char temp = array[b];
        array[b] = array[c];
        array[c] = temp;
    }
}
int checkWin(char guess[], char word[])
{
    int a = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
    {
        if(guess[i] == word[i])
            a++;
    }
    if(a==5)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

when the user guesses the string it works fine but when i try to display the scrambled string i get something like:

```
The jumled word is: ollehhello"
Enter a guess: hello

You win!
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 9.645 s
Press any key to continue.
```

i don't know what is going wrong with the string so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please write the code thinking that it's for humans. If code was only written for compilers, then it shouldn't need to be written in english.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your strings aren't `NUL` terminated, so the `%s` format code is running through both of them (stack variables are typically laid out back to back if no alignment padding is needed, though this is by no means guaranteed by the standard) until it finally finds a coincidentally `NUL` byte (on another compiler, it might print quite a bit more gibberish or crash).

To fix, use string literals (that implicitly add a `\0`), add the `\0` manually, or size them one larger than you initialize (the extra elements are implicitly zero-ed) e.g.:

```
// Not declaring sizes; the arrays size based on the literal to size 6
char word[] = "hello";
char scramble[] = "hello";
```

or

```
// Again, autosizing to 6
char word[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
char scramble[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
```

or

```
// Explicit sizing to 6, implicit initialization of uninitialized element to 0
char word[6] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
char scramble[6] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
```

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem :) ill accept answer when i can